# Odoo search domain condition1 and (condition2 or condition3)

Tags: odoo

I am trying to construct an Odoo domain query with a logic of
(Condition 1) AND (Condition 2 OR Condition3)

This is the code I've written:

```
moves = self.env['account.move'].search(
     [(
     "&",
          ('sftp_uploaded', '=', False),
        "|",
          ('move_type', 'in', ['entry']),
          ('move_type', 'in', ['out_receipt']),
      )], limit=200)
```

Running this returns a strange error

> ValueError: <class 'TypeError'>: "unhashable type: 'list'" while
> evaluating 'model._sftp_cron_action()'

In the same function the following code works fine

```
moves = self.env['account.move'].search(
    [(
        'move_type', 'in', ['out_invoice']),
        ('sftp_uploaded', '=', False
    )], limit=20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one extra pair of parentheses.

```py
moves = self.env['account.move'].search(
     [
     "&",
          ('sftp_uploaded', '=', False),
        "|",
          ('move_type', 'in', ['entry']),
          ('move_type', 'in', ['out_receipt']),
      ], limit=200)
```